# How can I UI test if autocapitalizationType property of a UITextField or UITextView is set properly?

Tags: ios, uitextview, xcode-ui-testing

Let's say I've a `UITextView` on which I set these properties:

```
    textView.accessibilityIdentifier = "autocapitalized"
    textView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Sentences
```

Now I want to  UI Test (with the new XCode 7 UI Testing Framework) if `autocapitalizationType` was set properly.
To simulate a user writing on the `UITextView` I wrote a test like this:

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let textView = app.textViews["autocapitalized"]

    textView.tap()
    textView.typeText("a") // lowercase 'cause I thought it'd be automatically uppercased but I was wrong

    XCTAssert(textView.value as! String == "A") // fails
```

The test will fail, so my question is: is there a way to simulate a simple keypress on Software Keyboard?
I mean if I run the test manually, I focus textView and I hit on an "A" on keyboard it's autocapitalized by default (because of the `autocapitalizationType` property): how can I double the same test automatically with the new UI Testing Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap the `A` key instead of typing text into the text field.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textView = app.textViews["autocapitalized"]

textView.tap()
app.keys["A"].tap()
```

**The last line will fail if the `A` key is not shown on the keyboard.** If the text field's `autocapitalizationType` is not set correctly the `a` key will appear.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)